# Is There A Built In IEX Command To Invoke Formatting?

Tags: elixir, elixir-iex

I checked h and h(IEx) and didn't come up with anything.

I am sure I can shell out to a command prompt and run "mix format" but I was wondering if I'm missing something. Is there any command analogous to recompile/0 or r/1 for iex to allow me to reformat the source files in my project?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can invoke the `format` mix task by calling `Mix.Tasks.Format.run/1` using whatever arguments you'd pass to `mix format`. For example, `mix format "**/*.{ex,exs}"` would be:

```
iex(1)> Mix.Tasks.Format.run ["**/*.{ex,exs}"]
:ok
```

Comment: Ok--just wanted to insure I wasn't missing some simple built-in command!